# term_link() filter or rewrite and howto?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, rewrite-rules

On a site where I filter custom taxonomy terms with FacetWP I'm trying to have the taxonomy term links go back to the homepage with the filters, instead of linking to the taxonomy term archives.

I am not sure how to go about this, `term_link()` filter or rewrite rule. Of the filter there is little info available and my own knowledge of rewrite rules is lacking.

Here is the single custom post type "site" on the staging site: https://sandbox-online.com/awidev/site/casa-azores/

the taxonomy terms are added manually to the single-site template, to showcase the differences:

```
echo '<p>taxonomy terms with links, rewrite set to <em>false</em> ';
the_terms( $post->ID, 'industry', ': ', ' / ' );
echo  '</p>';

$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'industry', ': ', ' / ' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );

print '<p>taxonomy terms without links' . $terms . '</p>';

print '<p>hardcoded link to homepage with correct facet <a href="' . home_url() . '?fwp_industries_dropdown=holiday-rental">holiday rental</a></p>';
```

So basically I would like to be able to change `?industry=` into `?fwp_industries_dropdown=`.

Is this possible with a `term_link()` filter and if so, how?
Or would this be easier with a rewrite rule and then again how would I do that?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am not answering exactly your question but in my opinion it is best to do it manually without messing with rewrite rules and filters. That way you keep also the default URL structure for terms templates, other plugins etc.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'industry');

if($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)){

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $url =  home_url() . '?fwp_industries_dropdown=' . $term->slug;

        echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        echo '</li>';

    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is looking to do it with the term_link() filter, FacetWP has come with a suggestion too:

```
// add the code below to your child theme's functions.php file.
function fwps_term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    // change the industry to the name of your taxonomy
    if ( 'industry' === $taxonomy ) {
        $url = home_url() . '?fwp_industries_dropdown=' . $term->slug;
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'fwps_term_link_filter', 10, 3 );
```