# Modify automatically generation of slug when term is created

Tags: terms, sanitization

I need modify the sanitize of slug when a **term** is created. For example I'm creating a term with name 0,5 and the slug automatically generated is 05. I need to add a dash in the position of the comma, the spected slug will be 0-5.

It's possible to do it overridind the code in theme functions.php?

SOLVED:

```
add_action('wp_insert_term_data', 'slug_save_term_callback', 10, 3 );
function slug_save_term_callback($data, $taxonomy, $args) {
    $name = $data['name'];
    $name = str_replace(',', '-', $name);

    $data['slug'] = $name;

    return $data;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched for an answer here? There are multiple questions and answers that are directly related. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change slug on post creation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation)

Comment: Hi @Steve I need the same but for terms no for posts, i don't known how override it in the functions.php of my theme

Comment: Take a look at the posts and this WordPress filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_link/. Again there is already a Q and A for this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259501/term-link-filter-or-rewrite-and-howto

Comment: I need to modify the slug in the moment of the term creation, I think that I need to hook wp_insert_term_data but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have bugs like this. because you are not sanitizing the title with `sanitize_title()`.

And you are not checking for duplications with `wp_unique_term_slug()`

Bugs tests:

1. Add spaces in the name and see the slug with spaces.
2. After you add the `sanitize_title()` add term with comma 5,5 add term with space 5 5 results with duplications.

So just fix this like this:

```
add_action('wp_insert_term_data', 'slug_save_term_callback', 10, 3 );
function slug_save_term_callback($data, $taxonomy, $args) {
    $name = $data['name'];
    $name = wp_unique_term_slug(sanitize_title(str_replace(',', '-', $name)), (object) $args);

    $data['slug'] = $name;

    return $data;
}
```